# how to create library which include its own layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-library

I want to build my own library which include its own layout like

```
 i. <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
        android:id="@+id/image_slider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
        app:iss_period="1500"
        app:iss_delay="0"
        app:iss_text_align="CENTER"
        app:iss_title_background="@drawable/gradient"
        app:iss_error_image="@drawable/error"
        app:iss_selected_dot="@drawable/default_selected_dot"
        app:iss_unselected_dot="@drawable/default_unselected_dot"/>

ii.   <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/directionMapRestaurantDelivery"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/directions"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:backgroundTint="#42A7FF"/>
```

i and ii are only examples

I want to create like that in my library, if you know how to make like that please help me to achieve that or can you please suggest me some materials where I can learn this stuffs.

Comment: Create a class by extending the view class like button, linearlayout  etc and create your own logic to create view. You can try this codelab for better understanding https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-custom-views#0